# Git bash in VSCode terminal can't find path

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, anaconda, git-bash

I mainly use VSCode and Anaconda for my Python Development.  I've always been more comfortable with bash scripting rather than powershell, so my default terminal is Git Bash (for Windows).  Outside of VSCode, things run smoothly, but if I want to execute a script in a different environment, my terminal can't seem to find the conda command.

[Terminal view of conda call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpjaZ.jpg)

As you can see, if I run `which conda` it returns the correct path.  But if I try to just execute `conda` it tries to use a path that starts with /cygdrive/.  I've deleted that a while ago, and conda works just fine in my external terminals just fine.  This only occurs in VSCode's integrated terminal.  Any idea how to fix this?

I've tried searching through the terminal settings in VSCode but can't seem to find a proper setting.  If possible I'd like to avoid a reinstall.

Comment: "/cygdrive/c/" is interesting. what if you remove the "/cygdrive"? Also, please add the output of `mount` to your question post. also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: Does it work in the vscode terminal if you run as `conda.exe` or the absolute path `/c/.../conda.exe` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case it's trying to run `conda.exe` but the returned path just ended with `conda` with no explicit file ending. Command prompts can get very fussy about that sort of stuff, and since MinGW is supposed to emulate Unix to a degree, there's a chance that the `conda` file isn't actually an `.exe` file to begin with. Make sure there's specifically a `conda.exe` file in your `Scripts` folder.

Comment: Yeah `conda.exe` is in the Scripts folder.  Again this all works totally fine within a separate terminal.  I only get these errors in the integrated terminal in VSCode.  For some reason it tries to add a `/cygdrive/` at the beginning of the path.  No idea why it's doing that

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to your environment variables, make sure the conda path already exists in the environment variable `path`. In addition, you can also add parameters to the terminal using the following setting in vscode.

```json
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
      },
```